# HSQLDB View (INNER-JOIN) faulty during runtime

Tags: java, view, inner-join, hsqldb

#### Setting

I have a problem with a db view. We are using Java 7, Google Guice, Hibernate 5.1.0.Final, liquibase 3.5.3 and HSQLDB 2.3.4. 
We parse a couple of files and save the data to the hsqldb (file mode). Then we use a combination of two views to collect the data for our file export.

#### Problem

So the problem I have is as follows:
Our select query will give us a different result during runtime compared to opening the hsqldb afterwards. [This is the problem simplified:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/malg6.png)

#### Views

These are are similar (but much simplified) to the views we use:

```
CREATE VIEW COMBINED AS
SELECT i.ID, o.* 
FROM 
    OCCURRENCE o
    JOIN IDENTIFIER i ON o.REF_IDENTIFIER_REVISION = i.ID


CREATE VIEW COMBINED_2 AS
SELECT
    combinedView.ID_OCCURRENCE as ID_PARENT,
    combinedChild.ID_OCCURRENCE as ID_CHILD,
    ConfData.DATA,
FROM 
    COMBINED combinedView
    INNER JOIN CONF_DATA ConfData ON ConfData.ID = combinedView.ID_PARENT
    JOIN OCCURRENCE combinedChild ON combinedView.ID_OCCURRENCE = combinedChild.REF_PARENTOCCURRENCE
```

#### Query

We the perform a query on the second view:

```
TypedQuery<ViewEntity> query = entityManager.get().createQuery("select v from ViewEntity v", VerwendungGeoPosEntity.class);
```

#### Table OCCURRENCE

I will skip IDENTIFIER because in my problem the data is irrelevant. In my case the data of IDENTIFIER is the same for all cases. I included the first view just in case it might be the case that having a view including a view is the cause of the problem.

```
ID     | NAME
------ | ------
1      | Parent 1
2      | Child 1
```

#### Table CONF_DATA

```
ID     | DATA
------ | ------
1      | Parent Data 1 
2      | Parent Data 2
```

#### View during runtime

```
ID_PARENT | ID_CHILD | DATA
------    | ------   | ------
1         | 2        | Parent Data 1
1         | 2        | Parent Data 1
```

### View after runtime

```
ID_PARENT | ID_CHILD | DATA
------    | ------   | ------
1         | 2        | Parent Data 1
1         | 2        | Parent Data 2
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before? I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: If the view does not return the same data after a restart, report the CREATE TABLE, the data, as well as the CREATE VIEW and the queries to the HSQLDB project. No point asking a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

While the entities for all tables where in the persistence.xml the entity for the view COMBINED_2 was not. :$

After adding the entity to the context everything worked.

No problem was indicated during run time. But when I created a JUnit test for this special case I got a message, that the entity was not mapped.